# html not displaying images only displays alt?

Tags: html

I have written the following html to add a image to a script that is being used to generate a email

```
<a href="http://www.marshalls-seeds.co.uk/" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.marshalls-seeds.co.uk/images/global/logo.png" alt="Marshall seeds logo"></a><br/>
```

If I check that in MS expression and outlook it works fine. But if I use hotmail or gmail the result look like this.

```
[Marshall seeds logo]<http://www.marshalls-seeds.co.uk/>
```

When I inspect the element I can see that the `<img>` has 'disappeared' and been treated as if it was text. But I cannot see why.

Comment: Do hotmail allow images? Usually there is some sort of "accept" feature before you can view the external images.

Comment: That's totally up to the email client - these days most of them block external images by default and there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: can you test it on html page is it working , then test it on email please feedback

Comment: it works fine in design mode on MS expression and through outlook, if that is what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is built-in security in gmail and Hotmail which removes the images.

Btw, you should always add `width` and `height` and en `/` in your `<img>`-tags.

```
<img src="http://www.marshalls-seeds.co.uk/images/global/logo.png" width="XXX" height="XXX" alt="Marshall seeds logo" />
```

Comment: Cheers I have added them now. What I don't understand is if I go to another email which has the display images option. The <a> and <img> look pretty much the same. But I am not getting a option to display images. What would I have missed to allow this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten  to close your `<img>` tag; now you can put `/` at the end of your `<img>` tag like this:

```
<img src="http://www.marshalls-seeds.co.uk/images/global/logo.png" 
     alt="Marshall seeds logo"/>
```